# Issue moving wordpress site to plesk

Tags: wordpress, ftp, plesk

I have recently been importing a localhost wordpress site into plesk. I have used ftp to move all of my wordpress files from htdocs on localhost to httpdocs in plesk.Ihave also imported my wp content to a new database on the server which I have set up the correct details for in config.php of wordpress. However, when I then try to view the website it at first showed a plesk default page and when I removed that index file from httpdocs, an apache default page that says 'You may now add content to the directory /var/www/html/ . Note that until you do so, people visiting your website will see this page and not your content. To prevent this page from ever being used, follow the instructions in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf'.

Sorry if i'm being dense but I thought that all web files should be moved to httpdocs if there isn't a public_html? Also, where would I find var/www/html/? as I cannot see this directory anywhere while using ftp.

Sorry again if this is a silly question but I am new to plesk!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Also remember to update your urls: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and for the datebase urls: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate php for your plesk site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where would I do that? I assume in the plesk backend?

Comment: I haven't used Plesk for years now. But it should be somewhere in the backend where you can configure your site.

Comment: Well, PHP support is ticked so not sure if its that. Super annoying, hosting company set us up on plesk and it is rubbish!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any domain in Plesk? 
Http root of domain's created by plesk is placed to

```
/var/www/vhosts/<domain name>/httpdocs/
```

You can check current apache's virtual hosts by command:

```
 apachectl -S
```

or

```
apache2ctl -S
```